# getAccessToken() returns code 215

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to have a page which gets tweets from a specific hashtag (Say for example, #Twitter). My code is giving me the following error :

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Bad Authentication data [code] => 215 ) ) )
```

This error occured after I changed this:

```
$tok = $connection->getAccessToken();
```

To this:

```
$tok = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
```

I am using Abraham's [Oauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) Library

Does this error have something to do with the change I made?

Edit: The following is all the php code from the relevant page.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('twitterOAuth/twitterOAuth.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('twitterOAuth/OAuth.php'); ?>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


if ((!isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) || ($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])=='') {

    $to = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']);
    $tok = $to->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);


    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token = $tok['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $tok['oauth_token_secret'];

} 

if (isset($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
  $ot = $_GET['oauth_token'];
}

$Content = $to->get('search/tweets', array('q' => '#Twitter'));
echo $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

?>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']` ?

Comment: I believe it has no value. I tested with the following code-

print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("The value is '. $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'].'")';
print '</script>';

Is there another way to check?

Comment: You mixed up JavaScript and PHP. Try `echo $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];`

Comment: Strange, I am getting this error when trying to echo.

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Can you show your full codes (at least few more lines)? You're encountering PHP syntax error.

Comment: Added the code in Edit! Thanks for the fast responses, @ShivanRaptor !

Comment: the code looks fine, but I'm not sure where do you get `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']`. This page should be redirected from server, right ?

Comment: Yep! Is there somewhere I need to set the value?

Comment: The other page should give you the value. Debug the value on the first line of code.

Comment: This page is pretty much stand alone, for all practical purposes. It does get redirected, but all the oauth starts in this page!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";` to

```
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```

in twitterOAuth.php. It will solve your issue.

Comment: This has already been done (Remember I mentioned that I updated my library recently).

Comment: Then are you sure you are getting your oauth_verifier at that place? and if you want to save that access tocken in database than and than this line require. Its good if you show some more php code...

Comment: This is all the php code I have! Rest is some html that is used to create a scrolling list for the tweets. Am I missing something?